# "Bake" Stage Type not showing in Stage Types Dropdown in Spinnaker Pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I'm trying to create a pipeline to Bake an image, push that image to a Docker Registry, then deploy it to my Kubernetes cluster. I am following the steps [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/hello-deployment/).

Everything is working fine up until I try to create the `Bake` stage. When I open the Stage Type dropdown on the Pipeline page, there is no `Bake` option in the dropdown.

Is there some config that needs to be applied(via Halyard or otherwise) in order to make the `Bake` Stage Type available? I'm running Spinnaker version 1.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the bake stage type is only available when deploying AMI's to AWS. So it's not a valid stage if you want to create a Docker image. Look at [this example](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/bake-and-deploy-pipeline/)

> NOTE: Kubernetes: The following example pipeline is predicated on running a VM based deployment solution (e.g. AWS, GCP). Comprehensive documentation of pipeline configuration for Kubernetes is incoming, as it is slightly different for container based solutions.

Here you can find some guides on getting similar results when using Kubernetes and containers:

- [Continuous Delivery with Containers on GCP](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/gcp-kubernetes-source-to-prod/) - set up a source-to-prod continuous delivery flow for a hello world app deployed via containers, on the Google Cloud Platform
- [Kubernetes Source To Prod](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/kubernetes-source-to-prod/) - create a set of basic pipelines for deploying code from a Github repo to a Kubernetes cluster in the form of a Docker container

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have actually read this page a few times. Must have missed the note at the top that you have pointed out! Doh!